# How to allow CORS on NodeJS backend application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to update my collection and it gives me an error which I don't understand:

```
Access to fetch at http://localhost:3000/collection/lessons602260eed5f3790ca8e87491 from origin null has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Here is part of my HTML page:

```
submitForm(lesson) {
    for (var i = 0; i < webstore.lenght; i++) {
        var newProduct = { name: this.order.name, mobile: this.order.mobile, title: webstore.cart[i].id, availableInventory: webstore.cart[i].availableInventory - webstore.cart[i].spaces };
        this.myArray.push(newProduct)
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/collection/orders', {
        method: 'POST', // set the HTTP method as 'POST'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // set the data type as JSON
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.myArray), // need to stringify the JSON object
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < webstore.length; i++) {
        var newProduct = { availableInventory: webstore.cart[i].availableInventory - webstore.cart[i].spaces };
        var lessonID = { lesson: clubstore.cart[i]._id };
        lesson = wesbstore.cart[i]._id
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/collection/lessons' + lesson + '', {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newProduct),
    })

},
```

And here is my server page:

```
// Import dependency module:
var express = require("express");
// cont bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// create a Express.js instance
var app = express();

// config Express.js
app.use(express.json());
app.set('port', 3000)
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // allow different IP address
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // allow different header field 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS');

    next();
});

// connect MongoDB
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let db;
MongoClient.connect('connectstring', (err, client) => {
     db = client.db('webstore')
});

// display a message for root path to show that API is working
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Select a collection, e.g., /collection/message')
});

app.param('collectionName', (req, res, next, collectionName) => {
    req.collection = db.collection(collectionName)
    // console.log('collection name:', req.collection)
    return next()
});

//retrieve all the objects from an collection
app.get('/collection/:collectionName', (req, res, next) => { 
    req.collection.find({}, {limit: 16, sort: [['price', -1]]}).toArray((e, results) => {
        if(e) return next(e)
        res.send(results)
    });
});

app.post('/collection/:collectionName', (req, res, next) => {
    req.collection.insert(req.body, (e, results) => {
        if (e) return next(e)
        res.send(results.ops);
    });
});

// return with object id 
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
app.get('/collection/:collectionName/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    req.collection.findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, (e, result) => {
        if (e) return next(e)
        res.send(result)
    });
});

// Update an object
app.put('/collection/:collectionName/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    req.collection.update(
        {_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)},
        {$set: req.body},
        {safe: true, multi: false},
        (e, result) => {
            if (e) return next(e)
            res.send((result.result.n === 1) ? {msg: 'success'} : {msg: 'error'})
        }
    )
});

// Delete an Object
app.delete('/collection/:collectionName/:id', (req, res, next) =>{
    req.collection.deleteOne(
        {_id: ObjectID(req.params.id) }, (e, result) => {
            if (e) return next(e)
            res.send((result.result.n === 1) ?
            {msg: 'success'} : {msg: 'error'})
        });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('localhost:3000')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only local, you can use a chrome extension to allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

You can search for Cors extensions for Chrome/Edge and install anyone of your choice.

Additionally, if you do not wish to install any extension, you can also enable it via nodeJs by installing a package `cors`.
[cors npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 0):

First Install - npm cors
and then add this to your file and it will be fine

```js
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`cors` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

```
npm install cors
```

To allow all  origins, you can initialize `cors()` without arguments.
Be careful not to do this in a production deployment.

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

// globally
app.use(cors())

// alternatively, per-route
app.get('/foobar', cors(), (req, res) => res.send('foobar'))

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Listening on port 8080'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your express server configuration is enough. The error comes from your client-side. You call an http request from a `null` origin, I guest your url will look like: `C://your_directory/index.html`.

I have 2 option to solve that issue:

1. Serve your html in a domain, ex: `http://localhost:8080/index.html`
2. Enable `no-cors` for your `fetch` request

```
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/collection/orders', {
        method: 'POST', // set the HTTP method as 'POST'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // set the data type as JSON
        },
        mode: 'no-cors', // new line
        body: JSON.stringify(this.myArray), // need to stringify the JSON object
    })
```